# Magento + Nginx Caching + Currency Selector

Tags: magento, caching, cookies, nginx

I have a Magento site http://www.burdastyle.co.uk/ that I'm working on, and there is an issue when changing the currency. The currency selector is supposed to add a cookie with the key of "currency" and the value of the selected currency, such as "USD", "AUD", etc.

The site is ran by nginx and it's also using nginx caching. I know it's the caching causing this not to work as part of the nginx conf for the cache block is:

```
fastcgi_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
```

If I remove that line, the currency selector works as expected, however if I add an item in my shopping cart, and somebody else views their cart, it shows the item that I just added as it appears without that line, all the cookie values are cached and served to all end users.

The full nginx cache block is:

```
location @fcgi_cache {
   fastcgi_pass phpfpm;
   #fastcgi_cache mage;
   fastcgi_cache mage_bs;
   fastcgi_cache_key "$mobile_request|$request_method|$http_if_modified_since|$http_if_none_match|$host|$request_uri|$cookie_currency";

   fastcgi_hide_header "Set-Cookie";

   if ($http_cookie !~ "X-Store=1" ) {
     add_header Set-Cookie "X-Store=1; path=/";
   }

   fastcgi_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires" "Set-Cookie";
   fastcgi_cache_min_uses 1;
   fastcgi_cache_valid 200 202 8h;
   fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
   fastcgi_cache_bypass $cookie_EXTERNAL_NO_CACHE $cookie_CUSTOMER_AUTH;
   fastcgi_no_cache $cookie_EXTERNAL_NO_CACHE $cookie_CUSTOMER_AUTH;
}
```

I tried adding "add_header Set-Cookie "currency=${cookie_currency}; path=/"; but it seems that after the fastcgi_hide_header line, the $cookie_currency variable is wiped out, so this didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I would recommend looking at using Varnish + Turpentine as an alternative cache that has hole punching which would then help you out here

Comment: Varnish will add more issues with session stickiness if not configured properly either specially with Magento.

Comment: Remember that cookies must include the domain. Try including all the information:

Comment: This is actually a moot point now. It appears that an update to Magento 1.13 causes nginx cache to break the "Add to Cart" functionality. "Add to Cart" now includes a url form key generated based on the user's session. With nginx cache enabled, this url form key is now cached, and not a valid key for users who hit the cached page, causing the users to go to an empty shopping cart page when hitting add to cart. Time to look into the Varnish setup which allows hole punching.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to test the app using and use LiveHTTPHeaders to troubleshoot the issue.

On the other hard, remenber to add the domain while setting the cookie. Otherwise the browser wont send the cookie. Here is an example syntax:

```
# I set the expiricy for 24 hours
add_header Set-Cookie "currency=${cookie_currency};Domain=www.burdastyle.co.uk;Path=/;Max-Age=86400";
```

Greetings,